# How do I touch moving buttons?

Tags: swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let manImage = UIImage(named: "man.png")

    let button = UIButton()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        button.setBackgroundImage(manImage, forState: .Normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: "activate", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(button)
        self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: button,
            attribute: .Leading,
            relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: view,
            attribute: .Leading,
            multiplier: 1,
            constant: 0))
        self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: button,
            attribute: .CenterY,
            relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: view,
            attribute: .CenterY,
            multiplier: 1,
            constant: 0))

        startAnimating()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func startAnimating() {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(10, delay: 0, options: .CurveLinear, animations: {
            self.button.frame.origin.x = self.button.frame.origin.x - 150}, completion: nil)
    }

    func activate() {
        print(button.center.x)
    }

}
```

How do I touch the button while it is moving? I read there is something about updating the hit testing, and using Quartz kit, but I did not understand the response because it just contained excerpts. Can someone please provide the simplest answer that involves my actual example code?

Thank you.

Edit: I would like to be able to touch the button where the image is currently, rather than where the button will end up.

Comment: Why are you trying to hack this using transparency? What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? There's probably a better (proper) way to solve it.

Comment: I just saw it on Stack, and it got upvotes and comment recommendations. If you really recommend it, then I will change the whole question.

Comment: I'm saying I don't understand what your problem is that you're trying to solve. Start by rewording your question so it's clear what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Ok I have changed the question. Please give it a read. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `.AllowUserInteraction` as one of the options for the animation.

Replace this line

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(10, delay: 0, options: .CurveLinear, animations: {
```

With this

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(10, delay: 0, options: [.CurveLinear, .AllowUserInteraction], animations: {
```

This will let you click the button at the position that it will be at the end of the animation.

To click the button at the current state during the animation you need to override `touchesBegan` method and use the `presentationLayer` of the button to `hitTest` the touch position.
Add this code to your class:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let touch = touches.first else {
        return
    }
    let touchLocation = touch.locationInView(self.view)
    if self.button.layer.presentationLayer()?.hitTest(touchLocation) != nil {
        activate()
    }
}
```

And to access the current position of the button you can use the `presentationLayer`'s `frame`, modify your `activate()` method like this:

```
func activate() {
    if let presentationLayer = button.layer.presentationLayer() {
        print(presentationLayer.frame.midX)
    } else {
        print(button.center.x)
    }
}
```

---

* It seems that as of iOS 10 there's no need to use touchesBegan and hitTest since `.AllowUserInteraction` is enough to let you click it at it's current state during animation.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't specific in my question, but the problem is that the button interaction only occurs where the button will be, rather than where the button image currently is.

Comment: I did exactly what you said, and it works beautifully thank you. But what did you mean by your * comment? When iOS 10 releases, all I would have to do is use your original solution? That will be much easier! Edit: Wait a minute, it already released.

Comment: Also, this override function seems to be for one specific button? How would it work with multiple buttons?

Comment: @ludluck yes iOS 10 is released, I tested this with xCode 8 and iOS 10 simulator and it worked with the original solution with no need to use touches began or hit test. I have to do more tests/research to make sure it's a feature of iOS 10.

Comment: @ludluck to add other buttons just add other if statements at the end of `touchesBegan` method like `if self.button2.layer.presentationLayer()?.hitTest(touchLocation) != nil {
        activate2()
    }`

Comment: That is good to know about iOS 10 and Xcode 8. However, there seems to be installation problems for some (including me). So I have to stick with the touches solution. As for my follow-up question, I have an array of buttons that gets re-initialized when the last button is used. So I can't really add over 100 buttons to this if statement. Is there a way to get this override function to work for all future buttons?

Comment: Use a for loop to hit test against them all. `for button in buttonsArray { if button.layer....`

Comment: Thanks for all your help.